# Getting 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to connect 30 times. Aborting' error

Tags: flutter, automation, appium

I am doing mobile automation using appium flutter driver on SoStronk mobile app(you can download the app from SoStronk.com) which is based of flutter. All drivers are working fine. After launching the app, it is showing the error -   UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to connect 30 times. Aborting.

Below is the code and log details

```
import Util.TestBase;
import appium_flutter_driver.FlutterFinder;
import appium_flutter_driver.finder.FlutterElement;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.PointOption.point;

public class SoStronkDemo extends TestBase{

    @Test
    public void test1 (){

        try {
            switchContext("FLUTTER");
            logger = extent.startTest("FLUTTER Switch Context");
            logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "FLUTTER Switch Context passed");
           // switchContext("NATIVE_APP");
            FlutterFinder find = new FlutterFinder(driver);

            driver.closeApp();
}
```

'''
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to connect 30 times. Aborting.
at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Ashishs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '2405:201:c009:bdd4:49d7:55e6:7524:31c3%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.0', java.version: '20'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

```
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
at Util.TestBase.setup(TestBase.java:49)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
```

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
... 36 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to connect 30 times. Aborting.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Ashishs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '2405:201:c009:bdd4:49d7:55e6:7524:31c3%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '13.0', java.version: '20'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to connect 30 times. Aborting.
at getResponseForW3CError (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (/Applications/Appium Server GUI.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:380:37)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1016)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
... 38 more

'''

Comment: can anybody help

Comment: Can you please check if FLUTTER context was available and please log it with driver.getContexts() and also, please print the complete error logs for debugging purpose?

Comment: Added driver.getContext() but it did not get any context.@BipinKumarChaurasia